# Why does scraped data returns None

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

How to fix this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl = "https://www.richilio.com/collections/chaussures-de-la-ville"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'}
productlinks = []
t={}
data=[]
c=0
for x in range(1,6):
k = requests.get('https://www.richilio.com/collections/chaussures-de-la-ville'.format(x)).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(k,'html.parser')
productlist = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"product-thumb"})


for product in productlist:
    link = product.find("a",{"class":"product-thumb-href"}).get('href')
    productlinks.append(baseurl + link)


for link in productlinks:
f = requests.get(link,headers=headers).text
hun=BeautifulSoup(f,'html.parser')

try:
    price=hun.find("span",{"class":"money"}).text.replace('\n',"")
except:
    price = None

try:
    about=hun.find("p",{"data-mce-fragment":"1"}).text.replace('\n',"")
except:
    about=None

try:
    rating = hun.find("div",{"class":"jdgm-prev-badge"}).text.replace('\n',"")
except:
    rating=None

try:
    name=hun.find("h1",{"class":"product-item-caption-title -product-page text-center"}).text.replace('\n',"")
except:
    name=None

whisky = {"name":name,"price":price,"rating":rating,"about":about}

data.append(whisky)
c=c+1
print("completed",c)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

so I was trying to scrape some data from e-commerce website but when I try to print out the name every single result is None, what is the solution??
so I was trying to scrape some data from e-commerce website but when I try to print out the name every single result is None, what is the solution??
so I was trying to scrape some data from e-commerce website but when I try to print out the name every single result is None, what is the solution??

Comment: Welcome to SO - Would be great, if you could improve your question by formating your code, so that indentation is correct and and issue is reproduceable. thanks

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is your `baseurl` concatenated with products `href` value it leads to an 404 (https://www.richilio.com/collections/chaussures-de-la-ville/collections/chaussures-de-la-ville/products/milo-nero)

Select the name only by referencing the class `product-item-caption-title` cause there is an issue with one of the other class names - Also use `strip()` instead of `replace()` or better `get_text(strip=True)`:

```
name=hun.find("h1",{"class":"product-item-caption-title"}).get_text(strip=True)
```

###### Example

```
...
baseurl = "https://www.richilio.com"
...
for link in productlinks:
    f = requests.get(link,headers=headers).text
    hun=BeautifulSoup(f,'html.parser')
    try:
        price=hun.find("span",{"class":"money"}).get_text(strip=True)
    except:
        price = None

    try:
        about=hun.find("p",{"data-mce-fragment":"1"}).get_text(strip=True)
    except:
        about=None

    try:
        rating = hun.find("div",{"class":"jdgm-prev-badge"}).get_text(strip=True)
    except:
        rating=None

    try:
        name=hun.find("h1",{"class":"product-item-caption-title"}).get_text(strip=True)
    except:
        name=None

    whisky = {"name":name,"price":price,"rating":rating,"about":about}

    data.append(whisky)
...
```